# Dynamically modifying Nagios config

Tags: nagios

We have a few services which will startup and shutdown at various times. Due to this it is not possible to include them in the nagios configuration upfront.
I would like to periodically poll a DB or a file to enlist the dynamic services and modify the nagios config so that they show up on the Nagios dashboard.
Is there built-in support for such a thing in nagios? If not I would be restarting Nagios everytime the config is changed by a background process.

Thanks,
Yash

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  This can be done using the Nagios 'Command File' interface.  For instance, I wrote an NRPE wrapper, called check_nrpe_retime, that uses the 'SCHEDULE_FORCED_SVC_CHECK' remote command to reschedule the next active check based on check results and other (external to Nagios) information.  I set the Nagios config up with the 24x7 time period, then all the timing is controlled externally by check_nrpe_retime.  Making it WAY easier to manager dynamic processes.  External commands are described [here](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/nagioscore/3/en/extcommands.html) and a list of commands is [here](http://old.nagios.org/developerinfo/externalcommands/commandlist.php).

Comment: This works if the list of services and hosts is fixed. In my case, services and hosts will be added dynamically.

Comment: Works well with dynamic hosts as well.  All of the procs I monitor with it are within a cluster and the host (or node) might as well be randomly selected.